# What are some good smartphone apps to help dealing with tilt?

Tags: software, psychology

Are there any apps for iPhone or Android that help dealing with tilt or when you feel you start getting negative emotionally?

I was thinking maybe that the app Mindfulness or such meditative apps could be something great and I wonder if anyone tried those in poker settings.

Comment: Tinder is what you're looking for.

Comment: Hehe! : ) I see people use it and they seem more stressed then meditative when using it.

Comment: How about Flappy Bird

Comment: Maps (either the Apple or Google variety). If you're on tilt, navigate elsewhere - even if it's just away from the table for a few minutes.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about an app, but I've always found it helpful to leave the table and go for a walk when I go on tilt, or even after a single bad beat. Physically removing yourself from the environment is far more helpful than staring into a screen.